# Why $(n!)^m\cdot m!$ is divisor of $(mn)!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, combinatorial-proofs

For natural number $m, n$, i found out that $\{\{\{a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n\},\{a_{n+1}, a_{n+2}, \cdots a_{2n}\}, \cdots \{a_{mn-n+1}, \cdots a_{mn}\}\}| \{a_1,a_2, \cdots a_{mn}\}=\{1,2, \cdots mn\}\}$ has $\frac{(mn)!}{(n!)^mm!}$ elements. This would be combinatorial proof that $(n!)^mm!$ is divisor of $(mn)!$. However, I want to know the 'straight proof' using number theory. Any help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think this does help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are $m$ runs of $n$ consecutive numbers, so $n!^m|(mn)!$.

Furthermore, the $k^{th}$ run (i.e. $kn+1,\dotsm (k+1)n$) leaves at least $k$ when divided by $n!$, which together multiply to $m!$.

Comment: The OP gave that proof. (S)he wants another one.